# How to Insert " - " (space before and after a dash) in cassandra using cql?

Tags: character-encoding, cassandra, cql

HI I need to insert a test like this in cassandra using cql:

```
INSERT INTO "MediaCategory" ("MCategoryID", "SubMCategoryName", "PhotoRankID", "VirtualTourID", "LangID") VALUES (6,'Mur d'escalade - Intérieur',41004,141004, 1036);
```

but after insert the data in cassandra shows up like:-

```
 LangID | PhotoRankID | MCategoryID | SubMCategoryName              | VirtualTourID
--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------+---------------
   1036 |       41004 |           6 | Mur d'escalade\xa0- Intérieur |        141004
```

The \Xao is getting into the data because of the space.Any idea how to escape it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the space is not a space, it is a unicode non breaking space: '\xa0'
I would guess you are copying and pasting the text from somewhere, and it is giving you a char(160) space instead of char(32) space.

Comment: Thanks this works.I included the space manually Char(32) space and it is working now.

Comment: @Zanson i have a data in a table in cassandra that has \xa0 as a trailing space, how can i write a cql query to escape that character, tired with single quotes, $ etc... nothing worked